# In python, do you have to import all dependent libraries within in the same file

Tags: python, import

I wrote a function called find_gra_index, which is stored in utils.py. The function uses timedelta from datetime.

I didn't import timedelta with utils.py, but imported it after I import utils.py.

The function find_gra_index keeps saying timedelta is not defined while I do see it is defined.

```py
from utils import *
from datetime import timedelta

find_gra_index(...)

NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined

timedelta

<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Comment: But `timedelta` is not defined in `utils.py`, which is the `globals()` that `find_gra_index` will use

Comment: Just import it in `utils.py`.

Comment: You need to put `from datetime import timedelta` in `utils.py`. A module should not depend on what the caller imports, so each module has its own search list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import timedelta into your utils.py file. The reason for that is when the find_gra_index_ Function searches for timedelta it searches locally on utils.py to see if it was defined and not on the file where it's been exported.